# redmine-gitolite plugin post recieve hook

Tags: debian, redmine, gitolite

I have redmine installed with around 12 projects and most of them are websites/web apps. Their code is maintained on the same server using redmine-gitolite-plugin by eric (https://github.com/ericpaulbishop/redmine_git_hosting.git). Till now everything is fine.

As most of the projects are websites, the current scenario requires me to login to the webserver and do a git pull to fetch the latest repo from the redmine-git server. Where can I write a hook so that each push to the repo is fetched automatically by my webserver?

Though the plugin has a feature for enabling Mirror repositories I am unable to figure out how to specify my webserver as a mirror. However I created sample repos at github and gitorious and the mirror config works fine with those sites.

I am running redmine 1.2.1 on debian with mysql and redmine-gitolite-plugin

Comment: Ofcourse, I tried editing the post receive hook in one of the project's repository but it is already populated with some ruby code. Probably that helps in showing the repo changes in the view of the plugin. So could not figure out a way to have owr own hooks alongside the existing hook.